# My website does not open after going from trial to payment on google cloud hosting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-billing

Good morning. I have the following problem: My account in the Google Cloud Hosting console was a test one, and when they sent me the notification to change it to a paid account, the via after a day, therefore Google stopped the services. A day later I put my credit card and problem solved. The strange thing is that 8 days have passed and my website does not open, and neither does my CPanel and WHM ip, call Billing and they tell me that everything is fine, to stop the machine and start it again, I did so, but, the site remains unopened. Any idea for a solution? I have not touched anything, this happened after the change from test to payment.
Website: ItalianaSpA.com

Comment: A common problem is that you did not assign an external static IP address to the VM. When the VM was shutdown and then later restarted a new IP address was assigned to the VM. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address